# Checking how long a request from mobile device to server takes

Tags: android, performance, http

I'm sending an http request from my mobile Android app to a server, and I want to print out how long the upload took. How can I do that?

Just printing out system time before and after the request won't help, because it also includes the time it took the server to answer.

This is my current request code:

```
HttpPost httppost = getHeader(uri, 0);    //fileSize);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = null;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

Log.i(TAG, "start execute");
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (code != 200) {
    Log.i(TAG, "http error! : " + code);
    throw new HttpException("Server returns with http error (" + code + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flow:

- Send to the server Android current time.
- Server should store time offset between server time and android time
- Next, Send your request where one of parameters should be time when Android sent message.
- Server will take his local time, add offset between server time and android time and calculate receive time.

Easy, right?

============================================================

Lets say android has time 14:23:01:010
Server time 14:23:15:000

Android sends request with his local time and server store offset
 (14:23:15:000) - (14:23:01:010) = 13.990 sec.

Now Android sends the message when local time was 14:24:01:000
and server got message when **HIS** local time was 14:24:16:050.

So (14:24:16:050) - (14:24:01:000) = 15.050 sec.

Now remove offset:

15.050 - 13.990 = 1.06 sec

This is your request time

Answer (score 0):

Simple save time before sending HTTP request and save time when it returns and then their difference will be the time taken by request to complete.

Comment: `Just printing out systemTime before and after the request won't help, because it also includes the time it took the server to answer.`

Comment: So you have to log the time on server when server receives the request.

Comment: well, good way but not for millisec resolution. First of you need configure server to show access log with milli sec field, after calculate difference between device and server .... But it should work for high resolution